# How do I link to a div in css and make the <p> have a set width?

Tags: html, css, linker-errors

I am trying to link the html to the css but am having problems and have become stuck. Any help is appreciated

ive tried using a div class but im new so not too sure what to do

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About UnixCast</title>
    <link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="head">
        <div class="head">Hi there! I'm Lewis and welcome to UnixCast.com!</div>
        <div id="para">
        <div id="para1">
            <p>If you're reading this I just would like to say a huge thank you for taking the time to want to know who's behind UnixCast. I'm a full-time student with a big passion for learning. I enjoy studying physics and hope to get a degree in astrophysics sometime in the future. I've always had a passion for creating content online. From when YouTube was at the start of its big popularity boom, I fell in love with the idea of sharing content freely for everyone to see. My goals for my content are simple:
                <ul style="list-style-type:disc;">
                    <li>Share my passion and interest with the internet.</li>
                    <li>Educate my self on topics that I find interesting.</li>
                    <li>Inspire others to learn about the world around them.</li>
        </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="para2">
        <p>And that's basically it. If you feel like you'd enjoy my content then feel free to check out what I do by visiting my<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPSlslWokRgiA3WEoMeqcFw?"> YouTube</a> and if you enjoy the content please consider subscribing! Have a great day and I hope to see you around!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #19181D;
}
.head{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.para1{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 120px;
    left: 5%;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Expected result is to get the html to link with the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know your level of HTML and CSS, but you need to call the CSS file to your html.
You use the .head to call your class = "head" and your #head to call your id="head".

Since you have 2 heads, I would advice to put different names ( to avoid any conflict).
`div="head_div"` and the other `id="head"` -> something like that !

And if you have your css file in a folder (lets say, called CSS) you need to define the path in your href (like `href="./CSS/cssfile.css`)

Hope it  helps!

EDIT : my bad, read your text and missed the title -.-
Just add a ID to the `<p>` tag you want to change and then do your magic in CSS (set the width you want)
`<p id ="something"></p>`
CSS :
`#something{ 
css here; 
}`